# Windows HTTP Proxy for programs that don't use system proxy settings?

Tags: windows-7, proxy

At work, I have to use an HTTP proxy to access the Internet. The proxy is set through a proxy autoconfiguration script. On top of that, I sometimes have to run a VPN to access part of our network. When I'm running the VPN, I have to go through a *different* HTTP proxy (and in fact use a different autoconfiguration script).

This all works fine for programs like IE which honor the windows system proxy setting. But I use some programs, maven for example, that have their own private proxy settings. It's a hassle to have to change the proxy settings for these programs depending on whether the VPN is up or not.

What I'd like to do is to run a proxy program on my PC, which relays requests based on the current system proxy settings. Programs like maven would be set to use this proxy. I've played around with [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), and it can be configured to operate this way. But it's a little heavyweight for my needs.

Does anyone know of a more lightweight HTTP proxy for windows that can relay requests based on the system proxy settings?